# Nested Buckets in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to compute 'nested' buckets in SQL, where each bucket is contained within the last. My query is:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN probability > .5 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .5'
           WHEN probability > .6 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .6'
           WHEN probability > .7 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .7'
           WHEN probability > .8 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .8'
           WHEN probability > .9 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .9'
           WHEN probability > 0.95 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .95'
           WHEN probability > 0.98 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold ..98'
           ELSE 'All Events'
       END AS "prob_buckets",
       COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM "decisions_table"
WHERE "ts" >= 1583366400
  AND "ts" <= 1583971200
  AND "model_hash" = '49bf554e65c72b844094dd547a2d71aebcda91c03aa806164f67f09cc6b2eddc'
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN probability > .5 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .5'
             WHEN probability > .6 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .6'
             WHEN probability > .7 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .7'
             WHEN probability > .8 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .8'
             WHEN probability > .9 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .9'
             WHEN probability > 0.95 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold .95'
             WHEN probability > 0.98 THEN 'Decisions @ Threshold ..98'
             ELSE 'All Events'
         END
ORDER BY "count" DESC;
```

What I want is a table, where the first row is 'All Events' and then the total number of rows in the `decisions_table`, and then everything below is all the events that have `probability > 0.5`, then all the events with `probability > 0.6`, and so on. The issue is that if an event has probability > 0.6, it also has probability > 0.5, and thus I end up with a table with only two rows: 'All Events', which is all events with probability < 0.5, and then `Decisions @ Threshold 0.5`, which is all events with probability > 0.5. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative sum in reverse:

```
SELECT (CASE . . .
        END) as prob_buckets,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(Probability) DESC) as count
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this gives me the same results. Was I supposed to keep the rest of the query the same?

Comment: @king_geedorah: re-order the WHENs to start with `>,98`, currently the CASE returns only two possible results, `'Decisions @ Threshold .5'` and `'All Events'`